# Broken pipe error when doing LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an unloaded file from Redshift in S3:

```
query = ("unload ('select * from " + str(table) + "')" +
             "to 's3://crm-files-redshift/" + str(folder) + "_'" + 
             "credentials 'aws_access_key_id=" + str(username) + ";aws_secret_access_key=" + str(password) +
             "' delimiter ',' addquotes escape allowoverwrite; commit;")
```

Once on S3, I connect to mysql with pymysql:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=port, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=schema, autocommit = True, connect_timeout=36000,
                           local_infile=True, max_allowed_packet=1000*1024*1024-1)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

And then to load the files to mysql I'm trying to do:

```
load data local infile 
'path to file'
into table mytable 
FIELDS terminated by ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

But at this point I get a broken pipe error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 927, in _write_bytes
    self.socket.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Notes: I'm doing this from an EC2 instance to a MySQL RDS instance. I'm not using threads of any sort. Python 3.4. The file gets downloaded correctly to the EC2, I even downloaded it on my Windows PC and made the LOAD successfully via MySQL Workbench to the same DB. The files are about 400mb each.

What can be causing this issue?

**EDIT:** I'm downloading the file to the EC2 and doing the load from there.

Comment: why not download the file to the EC2 instance and load it form there?

Comment: Just edited the question, that's precisely what I'm doing :)